# No launcher or menu in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity, launcher, login, menu

I am not very good with Ubuntu as of yet so I would appreciate an oversimplified explanation of the answer if anyone has one. I have Ubuntu 12.10 and have not updated or tried to update in a while but one day when i logged in I was only greeted with my desktop background and shortcuts. There was no launcher on the left or menu at the top. I logged in with the gnome interface and that work fine but the Unity desktop has major issues! Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you click <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key this should display both the launcher and the menu.